# Dynamic Prolog predicate with incrementing component

Tags: prolog, global-variables, swi-prolog, prolog-assert

I have a knowledge base consisting of a set of rules whose head of each rule performs assert or retract of complex terms when certain conditions occur.

How can I ensure that `Id` is incremented with each 
`assert(term(Id,A,B,C))`?

Comment: Yes i would sequential

Comment: What about `retract`? How should the resulting "holes" be dealt with?

Comment: Of interest: SWI-Prolog [Delimited continuations](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=delcont)

Comment: @GuyCoder. (1) I don't see the tag "identity" as helpful. (2) "sequentially" is superfluous. "incremented" means "+1"; not "+2"; not "+1.5".

Comment: @GuyCoder. I do see some merit in you adding "sequentially", though. It's a bit of a wording problem... multiple increments are done in sequence, but I don't think that misunderstandings are likely.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you don't care about holes in the `Id` (which occur when retracting `id_person/2` clauses) you could do:

```
:- dynamic nextID/1.
:- dynamic id_person/2.
nextID(0).

assertz_person(P) :-
   nextID(I),
   retract(nextID(I)),
   I1 is I+1,
   assertz(nextID(I1)),
   assertz(id_person(I,P)).
```

Sample use (works with SWI-Prolog 8.0.0 and SICStus Prolog 4.5.0):

```
?- id_person(I,P).
false.

?- assertz_person(joan), id_person(I,P).
I = 0, P = joan.

?- assertz_person(al), assertz_person(ian), id_person(I,P).
   I = 0, P = joan
;  I = 1, P = al
;  I = 2, P = ian.
```

Comment: `assert/1` is legacy; `assertz/1` (or `asserta/1`) is standard. Also, you can avoid the if-then-else construct by using an `initialization/1` directive to initialize the `current_id /1` predicate.

Comment: @PauloMoura. Right! Old habits:) Is the initialization directive (in this case) any better than a simple fact? (It is an additional concept.)

Comment: I don't think you need both `nextID(I), retract(nextID(I))`, I think `retract(nextID(I))` is sufficient.

Comment: @DanielLyons. Good idea. But the SICStus manual (https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/ref_002dmdb_002drcd_002defu.html) got me a bit uneasy, will check that out tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: It would be problematic _if_ `nextID/1` were nondeterministic, but absent threads it should only ever have one solution. If you have threads, then you have other problems anyway (you need a critical section or a lock).

Comment: @DanielLyons. You're right. It works. And a bit faster, too.

Comment: @repeat I'm going to have that comment framed

Answer (score 5):

As you're asserting clauses for a `term/3` predicate where the first argument is a unique (integer) identifier, there's no need for an auxiliary dynamic predicate to represent the current counter. You can simply do instead:

```
:- dynamic(term/3).

assert_term(A, B, C) :-
    (   term(Id, _, _, _) ->
        NextId is Id + 1
    ;   NextId is 1
    ),
    asserta(term(NextId, A, B, C)).
```

The call to `asserta/1` will make the latest asserted clause for `term/3` to be the first to be retrieved when called, as above, with all arguments unbound, thus providing access to the last count. This solution assumes, however, that the clauses are not being retracted arbitrarily.